# Syntax sugar of OCaml functors

Tags: syntax, ocaml, functor

Why is it that given:

```
module type ENTRY = sig type t end       
module type LOG = functor (E : ENTRY) -> sig type t end
```

This is a valid implementation of LOG

```
module Log :LOG  = functor (LogEntry : ENTRY) -> 
  struct  type t = LogEntry.t list end
```

But this isn't

```
module Log (LogEntry: ENTRY) :LOG  = struct
type t = LogEntry.t list end

Error: Signature mismatch:                                                                                                             
Modules do not match: sig type t = LogEntry.t list end is not included in LOG
```

If I remove the sig label (:LOG) from both definitions of Log then they return the same type  as they are just syntactic sugar[1]

[1] http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora132.html

Comment: using OCaml compiler version 4.01.0

Answer (score 3):

The error message is confusing but the reason the first example passes and the second fails is actually very simple. Compare:

```
type entry = int
type log = int -> string
let log : log = fun s -> string_of_int s
```

and

```
let log (s : entry) : log = string_of_int s
```

The error message in case of modules states that a module field is not included in a functor, because an un-applied functor does not have fields.

ETA: a functor logically cannot have fields: functions/functors are a "different sort of beasts" than datastructures / modules. -- This makes the error message confusing, it sounds like we are asked to introduce a field although it already is present in the *result* of the functor.

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify on **lukstafi**'s answer.
`LOG` is the type of the functor, in the first case it is matched against `Log` implementation itself (which happens to be a functor indeed), but in the second case it is matched against the result of the functor application (which happens to be an ordinary module), hence the mismatch.

All in all it looks like syntax misunderstanding. Read carefully the [section on module types in the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/modtypes.html#sec188).